# Building View Matrix in Direct3D11

Tags: mathematics, matrix, directx11

Am I doing it right? I converted this.

```
m_ViewMatrix = XMMatrixLookAtLH(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position), lookAtVector, upVector);
```

to this one.

```
XMVECTOR vz = XMVector3Normalize( lookAtVector - XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position) );
XMVECTOR vx = XMVector3Normalize( XMVector3Cross( upVector, vz ) );
XMVECTOR vy = XMVector3Cross( vz, vx );

m_ViewMatrix.r[0] = vx;
m_ViewMatrix.r[1] = vy;
m_ViewMatrix.r[2] = vz;
m_ViewMatrix.r[3] = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position);

m_ViewMatrix.r[0].m128_f32[3] = 0.0f;
m_ViewMatrix.r[1].m128_f32[3] = 0.0f;
m_ViewMatrix.r[2].m128_f32[3] = 0.0f;
m_ViewMatrix.r[3].m128_f32[3] = 1.0f;

m_ViewMatrix = XMMatrixInverse( &XMMatrixDeterminant(m_ViewMatrix), m_ViewMatrix );
```

Everything looks fine when I run it. Another question is, I saw on this site(http://webglfactory.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-create-view-matrix.html) that he subtracted lookat from position in his vector vz. I tried it but gave me wrong view matrix. Can anyone check my code. I'm studying linear algebra right now. Sucks my course doesn't have one.

Thank you,
Balls

Answer (score 2):

First, [XMMatrixInverse()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixinverse) first parameter is annotated as output, so for **XNAMath** it should be:

```
XMVECTOR vDeterminant;
m_ViewMatrix = XMMatrixInverse( &vDeterminant, m_ViewMatrix );
```

or for **DirectxMath**:

```
m_ViewMatrix = XMMatrixInverse( nullptr, m_ViewMatrix );
```

Second, if you look at implementation of [XMMatrixLookAtLH()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixlookatlh), you will find something like this:

```
XMMATRIX XMMatrixLookAtLH( FXMVECTOR EyePosition, FXMVECTOR FocusPosition, FXMVECTOR UpDirection )
{
    XMVECTOR EyeDirection = XMVectorSubtract( FocusPosition, EyePosition );

    XMVECTOR R2 = XMVector3Normalize( EyeDirection );

    XMVECTOR R0 = XMVector3Cross( UpDirection, R2 );
    R0 = XMVector3Normalize( R0 );

    XMVECTOR R1 = XMVector3Cross( R2, R0 );

    XMVECTOR NegEyePosition = XMVectorNegate( EyePosition );

    XMVECTOR D0 = XMVector3Dot( R0, NegEyePosition );
    XMVECTOR D1 = XMVector3Dot( R1, NegEyePosition );
    XMVECTOR D2 = XMVector3Dot( R2, NegEyePosition );

    XMMATRIX M;
    M.r[0] = XMVectorSelect( D0, R0, g_XMSelect1110.v );
    M.r[1] = XMVectorSelect( D1, R1, g_XMSelect1110.v );
    M.r[2] = XMVectorSelect( D2, R2, g_XMSelect1110.v );
    M.r[3] = g_XMIdentityR3.v;

    M = XMMatrixTranspose( M );

    return M;
}
```

Your link refer to OpenGL matrix, but you are using DirectX functions, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695520/how-to-adapt-directx-style-world-view-projection-matrices-to-opengl) for differences between them.

EDIT: Implementation is in `DirectXMathMatrix.inl` or `xnamathmatrix.inl`,you can find them in DirectX SDK, or Windows 8.0 SDK, or download it [here](https://walbourn.github.io/xna-math-version-2-05-smoothing-the-transition-to-directxmath/).

Comment: Thanks!! May I know where did you find the implementations? I can't find it on the link you provided. Thank you again.